# Java getIntent.getStringExtra is returning null

Tags: java, android

getIntent keeps returning null and I cannot figure out what the problem is. i used putExtra() which should store the strings, and I am calling it using getIntent.getStringExtra() in another activity.

This is the activity with the putExtra()

```
    String lati = tvLatitude.getText().toString();
    String lng = tvLongitude.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("lati", lati);
    i.putExtra("lng", lng);
```

This is the activity with getIntent()

```
if (getIntent().getStringExtra("lati") != null && (getIntent().getStringExtra("lng") != null)){
String lati = bundle.getString("lati");
String lng = bundle.getString("lng");
addEntry(title, desc, lati, lng);
Intent i_note = new Intent(NoteActivity.this, GoogleMaps.class);
startActivity(i_note);
```

and I'm using this line of code to check if it is null, in which it does return null:

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("lati") == null && (getIntent().getIntExtra("lng", 0) == 0))
{
 invalid = true;
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude and longitude is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Okay, so the problem is that the values are doubles, so now I'm trying to figure out how to convert double to string. This is what i have:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" +  location.getLatitude());
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    // Storing latitude and longitude to string
    String lati = tvLatitude.getText().toString();
    String lng = tvLongitude.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("lati", lati);
    i.putExtra("lng", lng);
```

EDIT: So I've stored the double as strings and it seems to be fine, but it's still returning null. Here's the new code:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    String latitude2 = String.valueOf(latitude);

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    String longitude2 = String.valueOf(longitude);

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude2);
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + longitude2);

    // Storing latitude and longitude to string
    String lati = tvLatitude.getText().toString();
    String lng = tvLongitude.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("lati", lati);
    i.putExtra("lng", lng);
```

Comment: Each code is from which class? Are you starting activity where you `get` from activity where you `put` by passing the intent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
//If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use this: intent.getStringExtra(String name) 

//In your case:

String lati = intent.getStringExtra("lati");
String lng = intent.getStringExtra("lng");
```

Comment: I just realised my latitude and longitude is stored as doubles. Would you happen to know a way to convert doubles to string values? Thanks

Comment: @user2905867 use `String.valueOf(double d)` and `Double.parseDouble(String s)`

Comment: Okay so I added these but it's still returning null. What am i doing wrong?

       `String latitude2 = String.valueOf(latitude);`
       `String longitude2 = String.valueOf(latitude);`
       `double lati = Double.parseDouble(latitude2.toString());`
       `double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude2.toString());`

Comment: print the values where u use putextra

Comment: I have it here as
        `i.putExtra("lati", lati);
        i.putExtra("lng", lng);`

Comment: yup i want you to print that varibales means System.out.println(lati+""+lng) and check the logcat and let me know the answer

Comment: Well I think the problem is the emulator doesn't support the Google Maps API v2 so I can't check what's happening with the lat and lng. Sorry, I'm new to this programming. I put 
`System.out.println(lati+""+lng);` after the putExtras, but nothing relevant shows in the logcat.

Comment: yes right , this the issue actually u r passing null intself :) and emulator does not support google maps :) u hv to test on real device :) .. i hope my answer was helpful foru

Comment: I have tried it on a real device, but it still returns as null. I've updated the code, please have a look at that to check if it's correct. They should be storing as strings now but still null.

Comment: ok just pass some hardcode values .. u will be sure if the getIntent concept is working properly